# What are the steps to bake Cloth physics animations into FBX for export to Unity?

Tags: animation, physics, baking, cloth-simulation, .fbx

I have the standard subdivided Plane as a Sail Cloth. Using Cloth Physics + a Wind Force to "animate" the cloth.

However when I export this to FBX and then open in Unity, my animation is not in the FBX file.

What are the correct steps to get this animation baked and exported correctly inside a FBX?

I have heard some thing about export to mmd > import that mmd back to blender > export as FBX, is this a realistic workflow, and what are the precise steps if so?

Otherwise what is the suggested steps/wokflow to make this work?

Thanks!